# Solr and nutch. How to save seed?

Tags: solr, web-crawler, config, nutch

Hi I followed this Tutorial

http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial

It worked as expected.

**How do I save the seed a crawled page came from to solr?**

I want to be able to query solr for a word "foobar" and get all the seeds that lead to pages containing  this word. I suppose I have to add a field in the schema.xml, but i don't know what the line in the file should be.

Comment: Could you please explain more about your problem? If you want to send some field to solr you should add some line of codes to solrIndexerWriter class. If you want to parse something out of webpages you should customize that by editing parser classes.

Comment: I have a List of domains. I want to download 30 pages from each of them and then find which seeds lead to pages contain a search query word for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any way in Nutch to achieve that; you could run Nutch multiple times, with exactly one seed at each run, and index the seed as a static field in Solr, via:

```
<property>
        <name>index.static</name>
        <value>seedUrl:theSeedForTheCurrentNutchRun</value>
</property>
```

This would work, but depending on how your seeds relate to each other, you may spend more time crawling (if a page is reachable via multiple seeds. Also in this case, the last seed would be the one recorded in Solr).

Comment: I have about 3000000 Domains so that is not possible.